# Error from reading an xlsx file using readxl in R "'path' must be a string"

Tags: r, readxl

I'm simply trying to use an excel file from a pathway in R and I keep hitting the same error even though my code seems correct and aligns with the readxl example.

```
data <- read_xlsx("/Users/......../filename.xlsx")
read_xlsx(data)
> Error: `path` must be a string
```

Im avoiding installing the xlsx package as I don't have a bunch of the Java dependencies and this seemed easier.

Update 1/5/21: I've gone ahead and just relied on `read_xlsx("my/path/to/file.xlsx")`. I'm trying to apply a function to this file so now when I just use the path as its name like this: `my_function = function("my/path/to/file.xlsx", a, b, c)` etc. it doesn't work and I get this error: `Error: unexpected string constant in "my_function = function("my/path/to/file.xlsx", a, b, c)`. So I clearly I can't use the path as it's name, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: You only need to use `read_xlsx()` once to import the excel file into R. If that works (check your environment to see if the `data` object is there, or just run `data` to see what is returned), than you're good to go.

Comment: will this work if i want to pull an updated version of this excel file from one drive everytime I want to run the rest of my code? (the rest of the code is a function to be used regularly on a shared excel file). I think if I import it then the file won't update.

Comment: If a change to the excel file is made (and saved), next time you run `read_xlsx("my/path/to/file.xlsx")` it will be with the updated version.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. Then when I need to refer to the file in code I use that path sequence as its name?

Comment: Yes - this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you've messed up the R "grammar" a bit. Let's break it up into 2:

## 1) Using `read_xlsx`:

I added some comments to your code to clarify the problem

```r
data <- read_xlsx("/Users/......../filename.xlsx") # This is reading your file into a variable called "data"
read_xlsx(data) #<-- So this line doesn't make sense, because you are trying to read an excel file, but the path of the excel file is what you already uploaded.
```

In other words, you don't need that second line

So to solve your code, change to:

```
data <- read_xlsx("/Users/......../filename.xlsx")

data
```

## 2) Trying to build a function

Here again you messed up the grammar.
When creating a function, it's supposed to work for all cases. So instead of defining the specific file you want to upload, you're supposed to write "path", and later, when using the function you replace "path" with your path.
So:

```r
# First define a function for "path", "a", "b" and "c"
my_function = function(path, a, b, c){
data = read_xlsx(path)
data
}

# And now to use the function:
filepath = "/Users/......../filename.xlsx" # This defines a string variable that you can feed to your function
my_function(filepath, a, b, c) # This runs the function on that string variable and the other variables: a, b, c.
```

You can read more on how to create functions [here](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/02-func-R/)